# How can I post nested JSON content?

Tags: strapi

I have two content types and they have a relation like this (please see attachment).

[my content types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGaeP.png)

I can post new content "`formData`" via "`http.post`" like:

```
this.http.post (this.rootURL + '/ communications',
       formData, {
         headers: {
             Authorization: `Bearer $ {this.currentUser.jwt}`
         }}
```

or

```
this.http.post (this.rootURL + '/ contactnumbers',
       formData, {
         headers: {
             Authorization: `Bearer $ {this.currentUser.jwt}`
         }}
```

Screenshots:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ldy.png)

[Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a16Tm.png)

[Subscribe Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrxnS.png)

But, when I post a nested "formData" as a "contactnumbers" (array) in "communication" JSON content, only the "communication" content is saved, the nested "contactnumbers" content not.

Is it possible to post data like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about all your message but.

All the documentation about dealing with relations is here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/models.html#relations

If you create a `communication` entry and you want to link a `contactnumber` entry.

This `contactnumber` entry have to be created before.

Then you will have to set the `id` of the `contactnumber` entry in the `contactnumbers` key of the `communication`.

```
// Create a communication
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/communications', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  contactnumbers: ['5c151d9d5b1d55194d3209be']
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I will test it as soon as possible, it looks like a good solution!
Best regards! :)

Comment: Your welcome, do not hesitate to set this question as resolved if it works on your side.

Comment: Hello Jim, 

Strapi does not support bulk POSTing yet. On 03.05.2019 I asked on Slack, DMehaffy (Not Strapi Employee) answered me.

Yesterday I tested it. Just posting a "contactnumber" is not a problem, like:
`contactnumbers: ['5c151d9d5b1d55194d3209be']`
but
`contactnumbers: ['5c151d9d5b1d55194d3209be', '2222 ...']`
works not.

DMehaffy means "depends on the relation type but basically yes" - I must post in loop, one by one.

In the meantime I changed my code like that.
What is your opinion?

Comment: What is the Strapi version you use ? and the database you use ?

Comment: 3.0.0-alpha.26.2 & MySql. :)